# Backbone view - created on mouse enter not firing events

Tags: backbone.js

I am using a jQuery tool tip plug-in that requires the use of the jQuery clone function to populate an auto generated tooltip. For the project I am working on, I don't have controle over when the tooltip is initiated nor is there an available callback so I am using jQuery .on('mouseenter') to initialize my event.

Anything I put within the initialize function works, but my click event wont fire. From what I have read, if el is defined then standard events (click) should automatically be bound but that is not happening and as far as I can tell this should be working correctly.

javascript:

```
Lot = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.wrapper = $(this.$el).find('.childDiv');
        $(this.$el).css('background-color', 'blue');
        console.log('init');
    },
    events: {
      'click .showChild': 'showfunction'
    },
    showfunction:function(e){
         this.wrapper.slideToggle('fast');   
    }
});

//gives the auto generated tooltip a class, otherwise it would be classless
$.balloon.defaults.classname = "balloon";

//tooltip needs content passed in, the tooltip creator recommends using clone
$('#showParent')
   .balloon({contents: $('.tooltip-content').clone(), position: "bottom right" });

// this may look redundant, but I do not have access to the initialize function
$('#showParent').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log('mouse enter');
    lots = new Lot({el: $('.balloon .tooltip-content')});
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="showParent">Hover</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="parentDiv tooltip-content">
        <h1> Some text to test parent</h1>
        <button class="showChild">Click</button>
        <div class="childDiv">
            <h2> here is a child div</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFkjZ/

any insite as to why the events may not be binding is appreciated

Comment: Why do you `$(this.$el)` when you could just use `this.$el`?

Comment: Because a person who 'knows' about backbone shared their tutorials with the world but apparently they didn't know that either or had their reasons and neglected to mention it.. thanks for pointing that out, and now that I think about it, it makes sense why it would work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `balloon` jquery plugin uses the clone and appends it to the `body` of the HTML when its first displayed. That breaks the event handler for your `Lot` view (as it means that the scope of the Backbone attached event handlers are no longer relevant).

One option which breaks the encapsulation would be to attach a document level event to handle the click in the way you want:

```
$(document).on('click', '.showChild', function (e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).slideToggle('fast');    
});
```

Comment: this is true, is there anyway re-bind the events? the trouble is I need to use backbone, what I have posted is a small use case and I really need backbone to handle the click event so a change event can be fired on the model and prompt other views to update.